# play2-scalate publish-local error

Tags: playframework-2.0, scalate

I am trying to use the play2-scalate plugin (https://github.com/adetante/play2-scalate) to leverage Jade templates in my Play framework app, but have encountered an error when trying to run 'play publish-local'.

Before I file an issue, I thought I'd check here to see if there may be an easy fix (I'm new to Play/Scala/Scalate). Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Versions: Play 2.1-RC1, sbt 0.12.0, scala-2.10.0

instructions are to run `play > publish-local` in the project-core directory, and here is the error I get:

```
[info] Generating Scala API documentation for main sources to /tools/play2-scalate/project-code/target/scala-2.10/api...
[error] /tools/play2-scalate/project-code/app/controllers/Template.scala:21: not enough arguments for constructor TemplateEngine: (sourceDirectories: Traversable[java.io.File], mode: String)org.fusesource.scalate.TemplateEngine
[error] /tools/play2-scalate/project-code/app/controllers/Template.scala:21: not enough arguments for constructor TemplateEngine: (sourceDirectories: Traversable[java.io.File], mode: String)org.fusesource.scalate.TemplateEngine
[error]   val engine:TemplateEngine=new TemplateEngine()
[error]   val engine:TemplateEngine=new TemplateEngine()
[error]                             ^
[error]                             ^
[info] No documentation generated with unsucessful compiler run
[error] one error found
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:doc) Scaladoc generation failed
```

It looks like it is failing on a documentation generation step; I am not sure how to get around this. Any advice is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears as though there is a binary incompatibility with libraries built w/ scala 2.9 and 2.10 regarding default parameters; see: 
[Scala 2.10.0 RC2 and optional parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13336819/scala-2-10-0-rc2-and-optional-parameters)

The solution was to modify the `project-code/project/Build.scala` to set the scalate dependency to `"scalate-core_2.10" % "1.6.1"` resulting in:

```
object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

  val appName         = "play2-scalate"
  val appVersion      = "0.1-SNAPSHOT"

  val appDependencies = Seq(
    "org.fusesource.scalate" % "scalate-core_2.10" % "1.6.1"
  )

  val main = PlayProject(appName, appVersion, appDependencies, mainLang = SCALA).settings(
  )

}
```

There were other changes to the `/project` files that needed to be made:

```
/project-code/project/build.properties
    -sbt.version=0.11.2
    +sbt.version=0.12.2

/project-code/project/plugins.sbt
    // Use the Play sbt plugin for Play projects
    -addSbtPlugin("play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.0.1")
    +addSbtPlugin("play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.1.0")
```

Hope this helps.